# How to limit ListFolder permission to the first level of the folder structure

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script that add the AD group "Domain Users" to a folder with only List Folder permission. The only twist here is to have this permission applied only to first level and not propagate to rest of the folder structure.

I am using this part of code :

```
$Permission = 'Domain Users', 'ListDirectory', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'InheritOnly', 'Allow'
$AccessRule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $Permission
$Acl = Get-Acl $folder
$Acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$Acl | Set-Acl $folder
```

I have some doubts about the inheritance flags that I need to use

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: So you want users to see child folders within `$folder`, but not files, and not to be able to see children of those folders. Right? Or do you want that them to be able to list child folders of both `$folder` as well as the child folders within those child folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the exact level you want want people to be able to see, so I'll cover a few things here. Let us assume this folder structure:

```
RootFolder
  - FileA.txt
  - ChildFolder A
    - FileB.txt
    - ChildFolder C
    - FileC.txt
  - ChildFolder B
    - ChildFolder D
```

This has a folder (RootFolder) containing two folders (ChildFolder A, and ChildFolder B). Each of those child folders contain a folder within them, C and D.

When you setup an Access Control Rule you specify the following things:
. User - What user/group you are applying the rule to
. Rights - What rights you are applying for (ListFolder, FullControl, etc)
. InheritanceFlags - What child objects should inherit this rule
. PropagationFlags - If they children specified in the InheritanceFlags should apply the rule to their children
. Type - Allow or Deny access

If you want a user to only be able to see the contents of RootFolder you would need to set your `InheritanceFlags` and `PropagationFlags` to `None`. Then the rule only applies to the object your are applying it to itself. In this case you would do:

```
$Permission = 'Domain Users', 'ListDirectory', 'None', 'None', 'Allow'
```

That would allow Domain Users to see:

```
RootFolder
  - FileA.txt
  - ChildFolder A
  - ChildFolder B
```

They would not be able to navigate into ChildFolder A or ChildFolder B. They would be able to see files within RootFolder

If you want the users to be able to navigate into those folders and see what is in them, but go no further than that you need to change the permissions for Inheritance and Propagation to allow ChildFolder A and ChildFolder B to inherit the rule, but stop them from propagating it further. Set the `InheritanceFlags` to `ContainerInherit` and the `PropagationFlags` to `NoPropagateInherit`. So the child folders will inherit the rule, but will not propagate it to their children.

```
$Permission = 'Domain Users', 'ListDirectory', 'ContainerInherit', 'NoPropagateInherit', 'Allow'
```

This allows the users to see the following:

```
RootFolder
  - FileA.txt
  - ChildFolder A
    - FileB.txt
    - ChildFolder C
  - ChildFolder B
    - ChildFolder D
```

They will not be able to navigate into ChildFolder C or ChildFolder D.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation and the examples. I was looking for to implement the fist example. I changed the parameter on the access rule as you mentioned above and it worked fine.
Thanks again